# How to know which list view item is being selected in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have 2 listview in my activity and i want to highlight the item being selected using the adapter in adapter class(`one item from the both the list at a time`), So by default i want only one list view item to be selected i.e the first list view item and based on the clicks on the listview the highlight should also change,that on both the listview the first item is being highlighted in the beginning and on item click the highlight changes fine.

My problem is that when i click in the first listview the scond listview items should not be highlighted but it is being highlighted why??

Here is my implementation:

I have initialised two adapter variable of the same class for the two listview

```
ListView list1= (ListView)finViewById(R.id.list1);
CustomListview adapter= new CustomListview(this,item,"type(it is string)")
list1.setAdapter(adapter);
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter.setSelectedItem(position);
........
});
```

and in `CustomListView` adapter class i'm doing the following along with the rest of the code i.e

```
 if (position == mSelectedItem && choice.equals("Strintype")) {
        tv.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
    } else if (choice.equals("Stringtype")) {
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the item position to check what to highlight, if you do so you'll have highlighted also the item in the same position in list 2; try using the item id intstead of the position (obviously there's more work to do) or use two different adapters for the lists.

Can you post the entire code for the two lists, including the adapters?

Comment: it won't as i'm giving the condition where it's checking the `type` which defines which listview it is